# Powershell $env with objects not working

Tags: powershell, object, environment-variables

I tried this:

```
$lst = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$lst = ("a1","a2"),("b1","b2")
Write-Host $lst[1][0] -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Works. Then this:

```
$env:lst = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$env:lst = ("a1","a2"),("b1","b2")
Write-Host $env:lst[1][0] -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Doesn't work (returns "y" instead of "b1"). What's wrong? If I work with basic data types the `$env:xxx` construct works.

Comment: Environment variables are strings.

Comment: ooh .. of course ... thanks